# How to make my Navbar links active when scrolled to the section?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

On my website I want to have the active nav link style active when scrolled to the section. It works when you click the link and it scrolls to the section but, once the user scrolls away the active link does not change from what was previously clicked. how can I have the active style change on user scroll?

HTML code

```
      <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#landing"><img id="brandLogo" src="project-images/portfolio logo2.png" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">skills</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
           
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

css

```
.navbar {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90px;
        z-index: 1000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1.5rem 8rem !important;
        /* background: #262626; */
        background: transparent;
        transition: 0.5s ease-out;
        /* background: transparent !important; */
    }

    .navbar .navbar-nav a{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e6e6ff, #6666ff);
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        transition: 0.7s;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-nav a:hover {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e6e6ff, #fff);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
         -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        /* color: #1b2735 !important;
        border-radius: 30px; */
    }

    .nav-item{
        background: transparent !important;
    }
   
    
    #topNav.scroll-menu {
        background: #090a0f;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid #b3b3ff;
        height: 90px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }


    #topNav.scroll-menu a {
      color: #0f1f3d !important;
      transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }
    
 #topNav.scroll-menu ul li.active a{

    border: 1px solid #6666ff;
    border-bottom: #6666ff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    
        
    } 
    
    #topNav.scroll-menu a:hover{
        color: #fff;
            
    }
```

JS code

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    let topNav = document.getElementById("topNav");

    if(window.pageYOffset >  750) {
        topNav.classList.add("scroll-menu");
    } else {
        topNav.classList.remove("scroll-menu")
    }

});


$(window).scroll(function(){
    let position = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.section').each(function(){
        let target = $(this).offset().top;
        let id = $(this).attr('id');

        if(position >= target) {
            $('#topNav > ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
                $('#topNav > ul > li > a [href=#' + id + ']').addClass('active') 
        } 
    })



});
```

Comment: check out [bootstrap scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/scrollspy/)

Comment: I tried adding the scrollspy but it still did not work, the active link stays on the first link when i srcoll.

Comment: Have you tried removing the space between `a`  and `[href=#'+id+']'`, so: `a[href=#'+id+']'`? If that doesn't work, try making a working code sample that includes the problem, so we can play around with it to try and find a solution. You can use StackOverflow's *snippet* option, or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/) work good as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I'm doing right or not as I'm a newbie to this area. But I hope this may help you as I referred to this code when I came across the same need.
"https://codepen.io/yohored/pen/aEnLd"
you may check this link.
or this may also help you http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

```
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>

.menu {
width:

 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{**strong text**
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add the essential part of the answer here so that's immediately visible to everyone.

Comment: As  I'm new here  I don't know much  to handle it properly, always welcoming your guidance to become an expert.